# How to do a recursion function that receives an array, find the sum of it and the integers in the array that divide the sum

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion, sum

I need some help to create a recursive function in C#.

The function receives an `int` array, which finds the sum of it and prints all the numbers in the array that divide the sum.

You can not create a loop inside the function or create a separate one.

My idea was something like this, but it's not working.

```
    static public void print(int[] array, int sumIndex = 0, int sum = 0,int devIndex = 0)
    {
        if (sumIndex < array.Length)
        {
             sum = sum + array[sumIndex];
             print(array, sumIndex++, sum, devIndex);
        }
        else
        {
            if (sum % array[devIndex] == 0) 
            {
                 Console.WriteLine(array[devIndex]);
                 print(array, sumIndex, sum, devIndex++);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"it's not working"* is not a reasonable problem statement for Stack Overflow. You need to be more specific. Please explain what's actually happening that isn't what you expect.

Comment: I would assume this is schoolwork. I would highly recommend learning to use the debugger. This lets you step thru the program and inspect the value of all the variables, this lets you verify your assumptions about what should happen. A hint would be to test the program with a small array, say {1, 2, 3}. What happens if you add another number, say 4? What happens if you reverse the order of the numbers?

Comment: Also. The question should specify "**evenly** divide the sum". Otherwise it does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good evening I believe your problem is you are using the PostIncrement operator not the pre increment operator.
change

```
print(array, sumIndex++, sum, devIndex);
```

and

```
print(array, sumIndex, sum, devIndex++);
```

to

```
print(array, ++sumIndex, sum, devIndex);
```

and

```
print(array, sumIndex, sum, ++devIndex);
```

The difference between these two is the first passes the value to the function (lets say 1) then increments it where the second increments it (so updates it from 1 to 2) then passes it to the function.

So currently your code would recurse eternally only processing the first value in the array!